# How to perform local sensitivity analysis in modelica

Tags: modelica, dymola

I want to do local senstivity analysis in Dymola to evaluate different parameters affecting the energy consumption in a building (for multi-familyhouse). 
Can anyone give me some suggestions, how to do it in Dymola (Modelica) software?

Answer (score 5):

You could export you model as FMU and then follow one of many the different paths for sensitivity analysis with FMUs:

- PyFMI + SAlib [Sensitivity Analysis using PyFMI - FMU in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357897/sensitivity-analysis-using-pyfmi-fmu-in-for-loop)
- FMI Toolbox for Excel by Modelon http://www.modelon.com/products/modelon-deployment-suite/fmi-add-in-for-excel/
- openTURNS + FMI https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321624302_A_Probabilistic_take_on_system_modeling_with_Modelica_and_Python,  https://github.com/openturns/otfmi, http://www.openturns.org/

...

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the "Design" library that comes with Dymola? It contains functions to sweep and perturb parameters.

You can load it in File -> Libraries -> Design. Some examples on how to apply the library can be found in the first chapers of the Dymola Manual 2. From the question I guess the Calibration package should be most useful for you.

Comment: In 'Dymola' I tried with this 'design library'. It helps to sweep one parameter.I have completed the Simulation for 'local sensitivity Analysis' by creating functions and scripts, because I had to Change one Parameter and simulate it multiple times to check there effects in energy consumption.
Is there any other way to do the 'Global sensitivity analysis' in Dymola?

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be to do the modelling in Dymola (or OpenModelica, Simulation X, whatever), and then do the parameter sweep, pre- and post-processing, plotting, optimization and so on from Python. Dymola has a Python interface, so you can start simulation, read results, change parameters and so on from Python. Everything that can be done from the GUI is in theory also possible from the Python interface.

A Matlab interface and a Javascript interface are also available.

Comment: I saw the Interface of SA, in python. But is it possible to do the 'sensitivity analysis' in 'Simulink' after transferring the model from 'Dymola'?

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a Simulink license, and do not use it. Also, I am unsure what you refer to with SA!?

Comment: by SA i was talking about the SALib of python.