# Performing Global Sennsitivity Analysis using Python after importing model from Dymola

Tags: python, analysis, dymola

I want to perform Global Sensitivity Analysis using Python after importing my model from Dymola. I have a detailed One Family house model in Dymola and want to perform sensitivity Analysis to check the effect of different Parameters,in the total energy consumption, throughout the whole year.
Is there any suggestions or examples regarding this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform local sensitivity analysis in modelica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353097/how-to-perform-local-sensitivity-analysis-in-modelica)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Dymola+Python you basically have two options:

- Either use the Dymola-Python interface, it more or less allows you to do everything that can be done from the Dymola GUI. The documentation is installed with the Dymola installation, just copy this URL to your web browser: `file:///C:/Program%20Files/Dymola%202018%20FD01/Modelica/Library/python_interface/doc/index.html`. Also open that directory in the explorer, there are some examples included!
- The other option is to export your model as FMI/FMU and then use [PyFMI](https://pypi.org/project/PyFMI/) or [FMPy](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) to interact with that FMI. As long as you want to change parameters only (and not the equation system) this seems to be the more "standard" way.