# FMUException: Could not locate the FMU in the specified directory

Tags: python, modelica, functional-interface, dymola

Using the code written in the link below:
[Sensitivity Analysis using PyFMI - FMU in for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47357897/sensitivity-analysis-using-pyfmi-fmu-in-for-loop/62045043#62045043)
I received the following error:
FMUException: Could not locate the FMU in the specified directory.

I would appreciate if you could advise with this regard.